# Exception Processing ErrorPage .The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found

Tags: java, struts2, struts

sorry I posted this question as there were many duplicates of the same issue.But the answer did'nt seem to help me.The error that i obtain is shown below

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/WEB-INF/error/error.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag
```

In the web.xml file I have added

```
<filter>  
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>  
    </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

struts.xml file

```
<action name="home">
            <result name="success" >/WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" >/WEB-INF/error/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I have added the `struts2-core-2.2.1.jar` file into the lib directory under WEB_INF Folder.Could someone help me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do not access jsp-s directly but through the actions.

Comment: tanx a lot for ur reply @AleksandrM.I have updated how my action looks like.Could please u check if anything is wrong

Comment: What url do you access?

Comment: Use actions that forward to JSP, when the action is called you can assure it's filtered by the struts2 filter.

Answer (score 0):

Since Struts 2.1.3, the [FilterDispatcher](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html) is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Since Struts 2.1.3, **use [StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html)**
>   instead or [StrutsPrepareFilter](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareFilter.html) and [StrutsExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsExecuteFilter.html) if needing
>   using the [ActionContextCleanUp](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ActionContextCleanUp.html) filter in addition to this one

Also consider migrating to the latest version of Struts2 (currently, 2.3.16.3), to avoid security issues.

Comment: tanx for the reply @Andrea.I have now changed filter-name in the web.xml to  `<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>` and still i get the same error